Error Using NPM After Installing Newer Node Versions with NVM
I've been having this weird issue. When I install any newer node version with NVM, I cannot use npm. It starts to give the following error:
Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/config'

Only time I can use npm is when I use node version 16.3.1. I've re-installed these newer node versions multiple times but still no luck. I am using PC with windows 10
